# What invokes a comma splice error?

Tags: commas, comma-splices

> The results of the study were inconclusive, therefore more research needs to be done on the topic.

According to what I read, this is a comma splice. So it will be changed from ", therefore" to "; therefore,".

I am wondering if this is considered a comma splice error, because the transitional expression is a conjunctive adverb.
Does this mean that if the transitional expression is a conjunction like 'so', the sentence would be considered grammatical and would no longer have a comma splice error?

Like so:

> The results of the study were inconclusive, so more research needs to be done on the topic.

Comment: [This question about furthermore is relevant](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/267997/using-and-before-an-adverb-like-furthermore); and [here's another question about whether comma splices are grammatical](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/416983/what-stylistic-or-grammatical-reasons-prevent-users-and-grammarians-from-reachin). [Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_splice) says that opponents of comma splices call for a coordinating conjunction not a coordinating adverb; but also notes that you can do what you like.

Comment: No, it's considered a comma splice error because the comma doesn't have the proper intonation to end a complete sentence; a semicolon does. So when you're reading along, the comma tricks you into not noticing the end of the sentence, only to find that another one has started, and you hafta go back and reparse.

Comment: At [Is it OK to combine two independent clauses into just one sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233348/is-it-ok-to-combine-two-independent-clauses-into-just-one-sentence/233604#233604) there is a strong argument that not _all_ comma splices should be seen as unacceptable ('errors'). The conjunctive adverb / conjunction issue is also addressed,

Answer (score 1):

> Which means if the transitional expression is a conjunction like *so* the sentence would be considered grammatical and without a comma splice error?

Yes, for the exact reason you state.